# Customize window store implementation in KStream - KStream join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We need to perform a Kstream - Kstream join with a very large window, where a tick on the left would trigger a join only with the most recent record on the right, and viceversa.

This is not how the default window works, since the `WindowStoreIterator<V>` returned by window.fetch inside the `KStreamKStreamJoinProcessor` is an iterator which can contain multiple records.

In particular, we noticed that the `RockDBWindowStore` has a `retainDuplicates` property set to true, and we would like it to set to false.

How do we customize the store implementation for KStream KStream join?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be to copy the code into a class with new name and change the logic accordingly? Another possibility should be to transform both streams into `KTables` and do a table-table join (you would need to disable caching for both input KTables.

Note though, that for the type of join you want, it hard to handle out-of-order data correctly.

Comment: I had to resort to a large JoinWindow to ensure output ticks whatever is the arrival order (left side or right side). Would the ktable ktable join give me the same properties?

Comment: KTable emit join results for input on both sides. This blog post explains joins semantics in Kafka Streams in details: https://www.confluent.io/blog/crossing-streams-joins-apache-kafka/